# UNIFICAR UN SOLO REGISTRO EN MYSQL EN UNA TABLA

Tags: mysql, sql

soy nuevo en el campo de mysql, me gustaria que me ayudaran con la siguiente consulta en mysql.

Tengo una tabla que se llamas "postpago" y en ella tengo 5 columnas, en cada fila tengo una columna que se llama "COID" y este valor es unico, cada mes me llega un archivo de los cules este codigo o COID recibe un pago y en una columna que se llama MES_LIQUIDACION dice 1 que significa primer pago, 2 segundo pago, 3 tercer pago, 4 cuarto pago, son solo cuatro pagos que hacen a ese COID.

Como hago una sentencia para que yo pueda sacar el la columna COID con los datos y cuatro columnas seguidas donde indique 1, 2, 3, 4.

[image: tabla origina]

que me saliera asi:

```
No. | COID     | NUMERODETELEFONO | CFM   | MES_LIQUIDADO_1 | MES_LIQUIDADO_2 | MES_LIQUIDADO_3 | MES_LIQUIDADO_4
========================================================================
1   | 279365400| 3137086132       | 46501 |          1      |            2    |            3    |   4          |
==========================================================================
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nos muestras que intentaste? y otra cosa, esto es para ver en la base de datos o en un sistema que muestra esto?? ya que por lo general, no debes arreglar problemas de vista en la base de datos..

Comment: Tu problema precisamente por lo que veo no es unificar, sino desglosar... y esto se debe a un mal diseño de tu tabla, en la que esos campos deberían estar determinados desde el inicio... no se entiende la lógica de que en (por ejemplo) el campo *MES_LIQUIDADO_3* siempre haya un numero 3... tu diseño mas optimo hubiera sido que modifiques tu tabla y agregues esos meses liquidados por separados y que almacene booleanos de los cuales, por default serán false.

Comment: Bueno día, el asunto es que me llega un archivo en excel con estos datos ya generados y cada columna que trae estos datos es una sola y vienen de esta forma. De igual forma lo tendré presente. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto parece resolverse con una tabla *pivote*, del modo siguiente:

```
SELECT COID, NUMERODETELEFONO, CFM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MES_LIQUIDACION = 1 THEN MES_LIQUIDACION ELSE NULL END) AS Mes1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MES_LIQUIDACION = 2 THEN MES_LIQUIDACION ELSE NULL END) AS Mes2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MES_LIQUIDACION = 3 THEN MES_LIQUIDACION ELSE NULL END) AS Mes3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MES_LIQUIDACION = 4 THEN MES_LIQUIDACION ELSE NULL END) AS Mes4
FROM postpago
GROUP BY COID, NUMERODETELEFONO, CFM;
```

- Uso la función de agregación `SUM()` para poder sumar cada valor de cada mes de liquidación.
- Como solo hay un valor numérico para cada mes, entonces la función `SUM()` sumará solo le único valor numérico para cada mes.
- Usamos `CASE`, para establecer la evaluación de una serie de posibles casos, en este caso el número de mes.
- Agrupamos por las demás columnas, por que al tener valores iguales pueden formar un solo grupo de valores y mostrarse en una sola fila.

Answer (score 0):

Agrupa por COID y usa una agregación condicional:

```
SELECT coid
     , cfm
     , sum(if(mes_liquidacion=1,mes_liquidacion,null)) mes1
     , sum(if(mes_liquidacion=2,mes_liquidacion,null)) mes2
  FROM postpago
  GROUP BY coid;
```

Comment: en la agrupación deberían ir las columnas que estás invocando en el `SELECT` sin considerar las columnas que se generen a partir de un calculo como mes1, mes2, etc.

Comment: Buen día, realice lo que me dijiste y me funciona muy bien, excelente, ahora el asunto es que me doy cuenta del archivo es que cada uno de esos meses tiene un valor de pago de comisión (columna con nombre comision), es posible que pueda salir así el reporte por decir algo COID | NUMERODETELEFONO | MES1 | PAGO1 | MES2 | PAGO2 | MES3 | PAGO3 | MES4 | PAGO4 |. No se si sea posible. Gracias.

Comment: @Aprendiz: No en MySQL. Desde el estándar SQL:1999 se permiten no-agregados, y MySQL implementa **detección de dependencia funcional**, la cual se puede deshabilitar con la variable de sistema `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: claro, se puede deshabilitar pero no es lo recomendado

Comment: @Edgar Amorocho: Es posible, agrega una columna igual pero cambia la columna del segundo parámetro del if: `sum(if(mes_liquidacion=2,comision,0)) pago2`.

Comment: @Sal: excelente ya estoy haciendo las pruebas y me funciona de esta manera ademas creo que tendré agregar otras cosas a la tabla.